# Running GitLab pipeline from a branch other than main

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, cicd

I've been stuck on  trying to run a GitLab pipeline from a branch in my repo and its driving me crazy. I have a sample branch called `test-branch`, but every time I try to run the pipeline manually GitLab shows an error message saying

```
Pipeline cannot be run
Failed to build pipeline!
```

I am the owner of the group hence by inherited permissions, I should be able to run a pipeline on any branch by default. I am able to manually run this same pipeline from the main branch, but for any other branch, it simply won't budge. Here is the `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file I am using

```
stages:
 - build_artifacts
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
Run-Pipeline:
  stage: build_artifacts
  script:
 - |
    echo "Somevalue" > file.json # Just an example script
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - file.json
```

Here are some steps I have takes to try and resolve this

- Change the actual pipeline steps
- Delete and recreate the branch with different code
- Scoured the pipeline troubleshooting docs, but I don't see this anywhere

This has to be the worst error message GitLab shows, there is no way for me to debug what is going wrong. What am I missing here?

Comment: worked for me with your provided gitlab-ci.yml (I just had to add `tags` field to target my docker shared runners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Apparently, GitLab has a certain naming convention for the variables. I added a user defined variable in the gitlab-ci config called `SAMPLE-VARIABLE`. Turns out you cannot use `-` in the name of the variable. Renaming it to `SAMPLE_VARIABLE` did the trick. 
However, it would be good for GitLab to give clear error messages rather than throwing such a generic message at the end user and expecting them to figure it out. I spent almost a whole entire day trying out different things to figure out what was exactly going wrong here

Comment: Good catch. Upvoted. Do you have a link to the documentation which would illustrate that variable rename?

Answer (score 0):

Check first the pipeline through the [Lint CI configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/index.html#lint-ci-configuration)

That will  test the validity of your GitLab CI/CD configuration before committing the changes.
An incorrect syntax could explain the runtime error message.

Comment: GitLab config is good. The lint check is valid I don't see any errors there. The pipeline simply does not start for some reason

Comment: Strange indeed. Try and simplify the pipeline until it runs, then restore it's content little by little.

Comment: Did just that! It was a pipeline variable that was the issue apparently. I've added the answer. Thanks for the advise!